# Creating a Stack like behavior is JavaScript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
  stack.forEach(function(element){
    //sys.puts(sys.inspect(element, false, null));
    console.log('-----element start-----');
    console.log(element.type + ':' + element.raw);
    console.log('-----element end-----');

    if(element.children){
      element.children.forEach(function(childElement){
        stack.push(childElement);
      });
    }
  });
```

The issue is that this is not behaving like I would except a stack to behave and wondering if this in an issue with JavaScript itself.  The issue I am seeing if that when I call the stack.push for each child to add it to the stack for processing, the initial stack.forEach() does not seem to be picking it up and it is only logging to top level elements. If I try to do another stack.forEach() directly after this one, it then displays the next level of child elements so I know .push is diffidently adding the child elements to the stack.

It almost seems like .forEach() grabs the data as it is and does not get an updates if they happen within the foreach.  Is this true for JavaScript?  Is there a different way I can accomplish the same thing (be able to process a top level element and all levels of children elements below it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supposition is correct. The ForEach function takes a snapshot of the array and any updates will not be processed.

You are trying to implement a classic tree traversal algorithm which can most easily be coded as a recursive function as follows :

```
  var stack = [];

  function traverse (element) {
    //sys.puts (sys.inspect(element, false, null));
    console.log ('-----element start-----');
    console.log (element.type + ':' + element.raw);
    console.log ('-----element end-----');

    stack.push (element);  // for preorder traversal (parent before children)

    if (element.children)
      element.children.forEach (traverse);

    // stack.push (element);  // for postorder traversal (children before parent)
  };

  traverse (document.body);  // for example
```

Comment: That's not entirely true: Only a snapshot of the `length` is taken, if you delete/splice or modify array items the behaviour changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does only iterate over the range the array initially has, it works with a copy of the `.length` value. If you want to change that behavior, I'd recommend a classical loop which queries the `length` property each time:

```
var stack = […];
for (var i=0; i<stack.length; i++) {
    // process stack[i]
    stack.push(…);
}
```

or even a more list-like behavior with

```
var stack = […];
while (stack.length) {
    var cur = stack.shift();
    // process cur
    stack.push(…); // with variable arguments, you want to stop somewhen :-)
}
```

If you don't want/need to maintain the stack yourself, a recursive function is the proper choice for tree traversal.